Numerically integrating photon wavelength undergoing gravitational time dilation
I am trying to integrate the wavelength of a photon that is undergoing gravitational redshift.
The formula that I'm trying to emulate is:
\begin{equation}
\lambda_{i} = \lambda_{e} \frac{        \sqrt{1 - \frac{R_s}{r_i}     }  }{  \sqrt{       1 - \frac{R_s}{r_e}     } }
\end{equation}
The code is:
// Post-Newtonian -- this is the gradient of the gravitational time dilation times the speed of light
photon_wavelength += speed_of_light * Rs / (2 * distance * distance * sqrt(1 - Rs / distance));

// Newtonian
//  photon_wavelength += 0.5 * speed_of_light * accel.length() / (speed_of_light*speed_of_light);

I am taking 1-second steps, and so the photon moves c metres per time step. I am calculating both a post-Newtonian and a Newtonian solution, which both come up with the same answer. The problem though is that I am also calculating a variable called wl_sortof_inf, which ends up being very close, but not quite the same answer. I am wondering if there is something obvious in the integration that I'm missing? Thank you for your time and expertise.
The whole C++ / GLUT / OpenGL 1.x code is at:
https://github.com/sjhalayka/gr_redshift
custom_math::vector_3 grav_acceleration(const custom_math::vector_3& pos, const custom_math::vector_3& vel, const long double G)
{
    custom_math::vector_3 grav_dir = sun_pos - pos;

    long double distance = grav_dir.length();
    grav_dir.normalize();
    const long double x = 2 - sqrt(1 - (vel.length() * vel.length()) / (speed_of_light * speed_of_light));

    custom_math::vector_3 accel = grav_dir * x * G * sun_mass / pow(distance, 2.0);

    return accel;
}

void proceed_Euler(custom_math::vector_3& pos, custom_math::vector_3& vel, const long double G, const long double dt)
{
    custom_math::vector_3 accel = grav_acceleration(pos, vel, G);

    const custom_math::vector_3 grav_dir = sun_pos - pos;
    const long double distance = grav_dir.length();
    const long double Rs = 2 * grav_constant * sun_mass / (speed_of_light * speed_of_light);
    const long double beta = sqrt(1.0 - Rs / distance);

    // Note: initial photon_wavelength and dt must be 1.0

    const long double r_inf = 1000000 * sun_radius;
    const long double wl_sortof_inf = wl_emit * (sqrt(1.0 - Rs / r_inf) / sqrt(1.0 - Rs / r_emit));

    // Post-Newtonian -- this is the gradient of the gravitational time dilation times the speed of light
    photon_wavelength += speed_of_light * Rs / (2 * distance * distance * sqrt(1 - Rs / distance));

    // Newtonian
//  photon_wavelength += 0.5 * accel.length() / speed_of_light;

    cout << (photon_wavelength) << " " << (wl_sortof_inf) << endl << endl;

    vel += accel * dt;

    if (1)//1)//vel.length() != speed_of_light)
    {
        vel.normalize();
        vel *= speed_of_light;
    }

    pos += vel * beta * dt;
}

void idle_func(void)
{
    // do not change the dt value from 1.0
    proceed_Euler(photon_pos, photon_vel, grav_constant, 1.0);

    positions.push_back(photon_pos);
}
'''


Can you explain your time-stepping method in terms of equations or generally known methods? You will likely recieve much faster and higher quality discussion

In particular, please state in formula what it is you are trying to compute, and what the algorithm is you are using.

Thank you all. I will update the question with more information.
